# Facebook non-official app for contact sync

Tags: contacts, sync, facebook

I want to remove official Facebook app from system because its a piece of crap, but I am not doing it because it syncs my contact with Facebook. I add someone friend and I get her phone no. and email id in my smartphone (provided her privacy settings permit it). It also syncs photos and missing data with existing Google and local contacts.

I have tried FriendCaster's contact sync. It sucks because of Facebook's privacy policy. Facebook doesn't share phone nos. and email addresses of friends to any app.

So, all apps which login using oAuth have problems with contact sync (correct me if I am wrong). I don't have problem sharing fb password to an app if it can do pure Facebook contact sync. Is there an app?

Comment: I could tell you some FB sync apps -- but as I don't use Facebook myself, I cannot vouch whether they fit your needs. If you are interested nevertheless, I'll list them app with a few comments.

Comment: It's not because of oauth. The official app uses that too. All apps must use the official API, if they don't they're violating the TOS.

Comment: @Richard I know its not because of oAuth. The point is: With oAuth, you've no choice other than official API. With password, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: And, as I've seen official Facebook app brings new phone nos. and email addresses to my smartphone..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [HaxSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mots.haxsync)? I use it to sync high-res profile pictures to my contacts, but I also use the Facebook sync, so I don't know which one syncs the phone numbers and emails.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can remove the official Facebook app in fact I also uninstalled it by resetting to factory setting and wipe user data.
and then I link Facebook account to accounts and sync. It works perfect for me.